# NVidia GeForce GTS250 driver issue

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, power-supply, nvidia-graphics-card

Recently at a lan party, I used a [GeForce GTx560](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-560) for which I installed Nvidia's **340.52** driver which worked perfectly fine. At the time I was still using a 32-bit version of Windows.

I have since been given an [ASUS ENGTS250DK](http://www.asus.com/Graphics_Cards/ENGTS250_DKDI1GD3WW/) card. Using the same driver and without any other hardware changes, the pc wouldn't boot.

**Symptoms**
The computer appears to boot into Windows, but right about the time when the Desktop should display, the system locks up entirely and the monitor loses signal.

**Important Information**
Basic PC specs are:

- Intel Core i5 3750k
- 4GB RAM
- PSU is 450W with 29A on the +12V Rail
- System Board is Intel DH77KC

After having installed a 64-bit copy of Windows, the problem persists.

I've been using Nvidia's **296.10** driver which is relatively stable. The system boots and runs fine, however some graphics issues are present. Occasionally graphical distortions and glyphs tend to appear.

**DXDiag**
Full dxdiag log can be found here: http://pastebin.com/W1TtchH2

If anyone can help me figure out what the problem might be with my system, I'd really appreciate it.

Some have suggested that the PSU isn't big enough to handle the card, but I pretty much discount that possibility in light of the fact that the GTX560 worked without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the Asus card you were given is faulty, so you need to confirm/refute that.

To that end do some troubleshooting; specifically, try it in another computer and see how it acts.

Comment: I have arrived at a similar conclusion, but I sadly, don't have access to computers whose PSUs are powerful enough to run the card at all

Answer (score 0):

Some of the older graphics cards allow booting only on computer that use a BIOS, but many of the newer computer use a UEFI instead or have both a BIOS and a UEFI but require you to tell it which to use early in the boot process if you want to switch between the two.

You may need to ask Asus which that card expects, and whether it has a switch on the card to select which it will work with.